# Finding control in Windows Forms panel

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, webforms, ironpython

I need to find a child control in a Windows Forms panel. I was wondering if there is a method similar to Panel.FindControl() of the ASP.NET webforms panel in the .NET Windows Forms version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve like this:

```
mypanel.Controls.Find("mycontrolname",true);
```

The documentation is here: [Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.90%29.aspx)