# Find control by name from Windows Forms controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a list of my textbox names, and I want to find a control by name. How is it possible?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx).

```
TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
tbx.Text = "found!";
```

EDIT for asker:

```
Control[] tbxs = this.Controls.Find(txtbox_and_message[0,0], true);
if (tbxs != null && tbxs.Length > 0)
{
    tbxs[0].Text = "Found!";
}
```

Comment: TextBox tBox = this.Controls.Find(txtbox_and_message[0, 0], true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox; Is it OK?

Comment: Getting this error.. .net framework 2.0.. 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you dynamically adding textbox into your form during runtime? If this is the case, you can assign a unique name to each textbox, and use controls.find to find the textbox with its unique name.

Comment: No i am not adding dynamically.. I have already list of textboxes .. And i have stored names of all taxboxes in one array. From that array i am fetching names and than finding textboxes and than want to fetch text from the specific textbox ..

Comment: The extension method 'FirstOrDefault' does not exist in .net 2.0.You need to be using .net 3.5 or later for that to work. Just remove the .FirstOrDefault() and the provided code should work.

Comment: TextBox foundTbx = this.Controls.Find(textBoxes[5], true)[0] as TextBox;

Comment: Change .FirstOrDefault() to [0]

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
f.Controls[name];
```

Where `f` is your form variable. That gives you the control with name `name`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the control is nested (you'll only find controls present at that level in the control hierarchy).

Comment: I try for example is  :
Button btn = f.Controls["name"] as Button;

Answer (score 5):

```
TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
tbx.Text = "found!";
```

If Controls.Find is not found "textBox1" => error. You must add code.

```
If(tbx != null)
```

Edit:

```
TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
If(tbx != null)
   tbx.Text = "found!";
```