# How to set winform control properties at run time

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Ok, I try to simplify my problem. I have a blank winform. A textbox control with name textbox1 being added to the winform. During the form load event, I retrieve 2 string values from database and store these values into **TextboxName** and **TextboxValue** variables of string type.

I use TextboxName variable to store that textbox control name (i.e. currently **TextboxName = "textbox1"**) and TextboxValue variable to store that textbox's text (i.e. currently **TextboxValue = "Hello world"**). My question is how to set the textbox1.text property without have to resort to following code:

```
If TextboxName = "textbox1" Then
        textbox1.Text = TextboxValue
End If
```

I mean how to set the textbox1.Text property without have to use **IF...Then** construct?

Answer (score 1):

Use `FindControl(TextboxName)` to get the control, cast it to a `TextBox`, then set the `Text` property on that variable. :)

See here for how you can implement FindControl - also a very similar example! : [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: +1 @Kieren Johnstone: I know what you mean, even though there is no built-in FindControl. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Huh. Someone gave a random downvote.  If this doesn't work for some reason, please say the problem, so we can fix it, rather than leave a bad solution here.

Comment: Your answer (the link) is helpful, maybe someone just directly use `FindControl(TextboxName)` and not work as expected.

Comment: You mean someone who doesn't read the answer might not understand the answer? ...

Comment: I don't know but the point is I have upvoted your answer long time ago. So the downvote not from me. I appreciate your answer.