# FindName in Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I create class, in which I need to find TextBox by name. Im using this, but here there is a problem, that FindName doesn't exisst in namespace.

```
object component = this.FindName(componentName);  
TextBox child = component as TextBox;
```

Can I use FindName method in class?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do, again? What do you expect FindName to do?

Comment: I have some TextBoxes and I need edit one of them by name. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx)

Comment: And when you say name, you mean variable name? And are the textboxes in a form that the code is in scope of?

Comment: @Crooker, if you're using Windows Forms, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls). If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, see [FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx).

Comment: Yes, variable. Yey, they are.

Comment: What are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.FindControl` (`this' is optional of course).

Comment: Still the same problem. Could be a problem with namespace im using? I think namespaces like System.Windows;?

Comment: I'm not sure about WPF. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls