# Dynamically change a button image according to database information

Tags: c#, winforms, button, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to change several button images according to what state I get in the database.
If I get any state "0" I should change the button image to a "busy" image, since the default image is a "free" one.

**So my question is: How can i change a button through a variable name?**

I have this code for now(i know its wrong):

```
private void checkSuites()
{
    SqlCeCommand checkSuite = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM RentSessionLog WHERE State='0'", mainConnection);

    SqlCeDataReader readSuite = checkSuite.ExecuteReader();
    int suiteIndex;
    string suitePath = "suite" + suiteIndex;

    while (readSuite.Read())
    {
        suiteIndex = Convert.ToInt32(readSuite["SuiteNum"]);
        suitePath.Image = NewSoftware.Properties.Resources.busySuiteImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is "wrong" in your code? What error are you getting?

Comment: I receive this error:'string' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID IT! Using a dictionary as Thymine said:

```
                public void checkSuites()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Control> btnList = new Dictionary<int, Control>();
        btnList.Add(1, suite1);
        btnList.Add(2, suite2);
        btnList.Add(3, suite3);
        btnList.Add(4, suite4);
        btnList.Add(5, suite5);
        SqlCeCommand checkSuite = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM RentSessionLog WHERE State='0'", mainConnection);

        SqlCeDataReader readSuite = checkSuite.ExecuteReader();
        while (readSuite.Read())
        {
            int suiteIndex = Convert.ToInt32(readSuite["SuiteNum"]);
            string suitePath = "suite" + suiteIndex;
            foreach (Button key in btnList.Values)
            {
                if (key.Name == suitePath)
                {
                 key.Image = NewSoftware.Properties.Resources.busySuiteImg;
                }
            }

            }


    }
```

Thank you all who helped :D

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
while (readSuite.Read())
{
    suiteIndex = Convert.ToInt32(readSuite["SuiteNum"]);
    switch(suiteIndex)
    {
    case 0:
       {
           suitePath.Image = NewSoftware.Properties.Resources.busySuiteImg;
           break;
       }
    default:
       {
           suitePath.Image = NewSoftware.Properties.Resources.freeSuiteImg;
       }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The reason I used a switch is in case you have other-states appearing in the future.  You have "Busy" and "Free", but there could be "Reserved" as well and you may want to have further conditions that would just get obfuscated in a simple `if else if` sequence.

Comment: Still having the same problem: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, I see your issue.  You need to be setting the `Image` property on your button, not the string itself.

Comment: Yes, it's a very good suggestion using "switch" but it doesn't accept the variable as the name of the button.

Comment: Where are the buttons defined?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `this.Controls.Find(suitePath, true)` to turn your string into a control.  I am presuming that `"suite" + suiteIndex` is the `.Name` of each of your buttons.

```
string suitePath = "suite" + suiteIndex;
Button suiteButton = this.Controls.Find(suitePath, true);
suiteButton.Image = ...
```

[See more details about Controls.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Alternatively for quicker access, you may want to keep a `Dictionary<int, Control>` with each of your buttons in it.

Comment: i get this error: No overload for method 'Find' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Whoops, you need `Find(suitePath, true)`  The boolean tells it if it should search children or not.

Comment: Now I'm receiving this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' :(

Comment: Ah, good that worked, that should offer better performance (even tho it would probably never be noticeable).  For `Find`, first it returns an array, so you would need to select the first item (you may want to make sure it returns items) then cast it to `Button`, either `(Button)this.Find(...)`  There are far more (unlikely) error cases to consider with this, as opposed to the dictionary method...