# Retrieve text from dynamically created textbox in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, vb.net, text, textbox, stackpanel

So I have a stack panel, and users click a button and it adds a text box in the stack panel. I got that down. The naming system is such that it names each textbox individually ("textboxname" + I). However, I have no clue how to get the text back from they textboxes to use elsewhere. Anyone got any idea for to get the text from a textbox that's a child of a stack panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Me.Controls.Find("yourTextBoxName", true)
```

Here passing `true` is necessary since it help to find the control in child controls as well. Since you have `StackPanel` over the root parent control and containing Textboxes.

For more info and a clear solution, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls).

**EDIT:**

You should use [this custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type).

Comment: is this for C#? On VB.net I'm not seeing a me.controls option, its saying that controls isn't a member.

Comment: Its VB.Net, where do you write this ? in module or in form.vb file ?

Comment: Ah... I'm using WPF... no module, no form. Sorry man I forgot to say

Comment: Look at my edits as well as this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bd6c7fb-a209-4158-8ac6-27c0b9620c45/find-control-inside-a-wpf-user-control?forum=wpf

Comment: It doesn't seem to be finding the name of the dynamically created text boxes no matter how I try. However, It looks like if I just take the StackPanel.Children(i).tostring it gives me the type and then the value within the textbox. 

Its a very very dirty method but I cant see any other way of getting text out of these textboxes.