# Get variable by name dynamically - Without Reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I am currently doing this one by one: to tidy them

```
             //created on the form1    
textboxs[0] = textbox0;  
textboxs[1] = textbox1; 
textboxs[2] = textbox2;  
textboxs[3] = textbox3;
```

Is there a way to convert it to the below somehow?

```
for (int i = 0; i < KSy; i++)  //kisi sayısı
{
    // getting the i as code (not variable)
    textboxs[i] = textbox+i ;
}
```

**update:**
this is what i wanted to do  :
[Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

everyone talks about reflection . i coudnt make reflection work

Comment: "Reflection" is the term you are looking for.

Comment: You didn't even bothered to tell us what are you trying to accomplish nor what does "cb_kisiLER" means or is, we're no wizards.

Comment: It’s possible; don’t do it. Either you have few enough that it can be manual or you have so many that they should never have been put into separate variables in the first place, and you should fix that.

Comment: You also should not have "textbox1" as textbox name - and when you have some more meaningful names your for loop will not be useful... If it is group of related textboxes - make them child of single parent and use parent's `Controls` list to pick your elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls  this is my resolvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `cb_kisiN` are fields you can do:

```
for(int i =  0; i < KSy; i++)
{
    var field = this.GetType().GetField("textbox" + i);
    var code = field.GetValue(this) as Code;
    textboxs[i] = code;
}
```

Comment: var code = field.GetValue(this) as Textbox;// null refence exeption