# How can i change the backcolor of picture box the number will taken from the textbox

Tags: c#, picturebox

```
private PictureBox[] picturebox = new PictureBox[64];
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
   int i = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);             
   picturebox[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

when the button click i will take a number  between 1 to 64  from user and i will change the backcolor of the picturebox which is want by user.

for ex:

```
int i=3;
pictureBox3.BackColor=color.green;
```

Comment: What the fawk. I don't understand, and no text at all in the question. A little effort please.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are having problems with?  are the picture box's rendering ? are you getting any errors? Is the button click event firing properly?

Comment: It's the user's first question obivously, you can comment and help instead of just down voting

Comment: We don't know if your PictureBox array relates to any PictureBoxes on a form.  You need to show us more code.

Comment: I think BackColor need the name of the Control, for instance, pictureBox1.BackColor. You should fill your array with something because, right now, if - let me say a random number - i = 5 , you are pointing to nothing and the code will throw an error.

Comment: i want to change one picturebox  backcolor which is  from 64 picturebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int i = 3;
string PB= "pictureBox" + i;
PictureBox pb= this.Controls.Find(PB, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
pb.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) you can find this example!