# A method to select Datagridview base on index

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My really first question here. I come from an electrical engineering background and I have always use C to write program for microcontrollers so I am pretty new to VB net.
Here my doubt :

I have different tab (TabControl1, ...2, ..3, etc) in a form and every tab page contains a datagridview (DataGridView1, .... ).
and 1 button in common in the form.

How can I populate by pressing the button, the right datagridview base on the selectecTab?

I would do something like this:

```
selectedTab = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
if selectedTab = 0 then populate DataGridview1
else if selectedTab = 1 then populate DataGridview2
else if selectedTab = 2 then populate DataGridview3
```

....

But this code is limited because if in the future I need to add more Tab then I have to add more line of code.

Can you show me a smarter way to do it?

thanks a lot

- Nihilo

Comment: Build dynamically the datagrid's name using the fixed part of the name and the index and locate the control dynamically (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls).

Comment: Thank you Luis for the quick answer, also for the useful link.

Comment: At some point I have the following code:DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(DataGridView1.Columns(0)).                How can I have the same line of code but with DataGridViewX where x is base on tab Index?

Comment: Thank you I solved it. I created an array of DataGridView control object and simply used it as following. dataGridMyArray(selectedTab).Columns.Remove(...)