# Access multiple controls via an array rather than individually?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

I wonder if anyone can help me with the following please?

I have 20 labels on my form, named "Name1", "Name2" etc.....
I want to read from a DB and populate each label with its corresponding value from the DB row.

At the moment the code does this the long way:

```
Name1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Name1")
Name2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Name2")
etc.....
```

I want to use an array and a loop to reduce the code, but I'm not sure what I need to do.
The below works perfectly, apart from instead of Name1.Text I actually want it to be Name(i).text = .......
Suffice to say this doesn't work, so I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
For i As Int16 = 1 To 20
    Name1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Name" & (i))
Next
```

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: You could use data bindings

Answer (score 0):

You could add the controls you want in an array (in the correct order).
Then use a For or For Each loop to iterate.

With your code it looks like :

```
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, etc}
For i As Int16 = 0 To textBoxes.Count -1
    'According To Matt Wilko, it's better to start from 0 to textBoxes.Count-1, so you'll have to use i+1
    textBoxes(i+1).Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Name" & (i+1))
Next
```

By the way, i'm not sure this is the best way :/

Comment: your loop needs to go from `0` to `textBoxes.Count - 1`