# Variable in C# for loop

Tags: c#, variables

I have got many buttons in my Application Form. And I would like to check every buttons text (compare). How can I achive that ?

```
for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) 
{
   if (this.button1.Text == "Hello") //here is PROBLEM
   {
      //..some statement
   }   
}
```

So next time this.button**1**.Text must change to this.button**2**.Text and so on...

this.button[i].Text not working.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, WPF, Windows App...?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a correct syntax:**

```
foreach (Control button in this.Controls)
{
     if (button.GetType() == typeof(Button) && button.Text == "Hello")
     {
           //..some statement    
     }
}
```

Comment: This code syntax helped me to solve the pazzle. Thanks.

Comment: Add stills gives me understanding of how it actually works.

Answer (score 4):

Buttons are not arrays.  Each one is a discreet object, and a child of its container.

Ideally, you need to build a collection (array, list, whatever) of the buttons and iterate through that collection, rather than using an index variable (i).

Here's a good approach:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/820068

Comment: you can iterate in windows form, and it's stated in the question that this is an application form

Comment: @Desperado - I did not assert that any of that was false.  You used exactly my approach by getting the panel.Controls collection and iterating through it.

Comment: sorry I didn't click your link, you're correct we have the same concept and I copied my answer from my old code

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that this is a windows form.
And in windows form you can iterate the controls like this.

```
foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
{
    string cType = c.GetType().ToString();

    // check all buttons
    if (cType == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button")
    {
        if(((Button)c).Text == "Hello")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So what the code does is to iterate all the controls inside a panel and check each control if it's type is a button.

Update: 
As Wesley said, much better approach for the condition is to implement it like this

```
 if (c is Button && c.Text.Equals("Hello")) {
```

Comment: Recommended:  if (c is Button && ((Button)c).Text.Equals("Hello")) {...}

Comment: _I'm quite sure that this is a windows form_  doesn't match `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

Comment: sorry for that @fubo

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var buttonName = "button" + i;
            Button button = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
            string text = button.Text;
        }
```

try this code.

Comment: This might work for the given scenario, but its not recommendable in that it assumes that all the buttons should be named buttonX which is not a good nomenclature.

Comment: I know that. But Casper want to do this kind of behaviour. He wants to find a control by fixed names. Exp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls