# How to find a Control by it's name in c# Windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some controls in my form inside a panel. I want to get value of any control if I know the name of that control which is Inside that Panel. So I did following effort....

```
foreach (Control ch in pnl.Controls)
{
     if (ch.Name == "ControlName")
          MessageBox.Show(ch.Text);
}
```

But this code loop through all the controls inside that panel, that's not my exact requirement. I want to find that control without any  loop.

May be my question looks like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) post, but that post is helpful when you already know that your desired control is TextBox. What if I don't know the type of my control ?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei, That post is helpful when you already know that your control is TextBox. What if I don't know what is the type of my control ?

Comment: The type of control doesn't matter to find it. Use `var c = this.Controls["someControl"];` like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3898599/3110834). Also in the accepted answer you can neglect the casing and just use `var c = this.Controls.Find("someControl", true).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: and how will I retrieve the value of var c ?

Comment: All controls have `Text` property like you used in your `foreach` example.

Comment: One more thing.....
  Can you tell me where this line var c = this.Controls["someControl"];  in that post  on the basis of which you marked my question duplicate ?

Comment: In my first comment I showed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3898599/3110834) of duplicate post. While the accepted answer is completely OK and answers youre question, but you should read other posts as well.  Also don't bother by mark as duplicates. I just tried to help and prevent new answers to an obvious duplicate, that's why I'm answering your comments while I believe the post obviously answers your question :)

Comment: Actually I don't know how to retrieve value from `var c`. So I thought my question is different from that answer.

Comment: You learned to find the control. Your next question is to find its value. The `Value` is not a common property between controls. For example a `TextBox` has `Text`, a `CheckBox` has `Checked`,  a `ComboBox` has `SelectedIndex`, `Text`, `SelectedItem` and so on. You can not have a generic way to get what you called value, unless you know you are working with what kind of control.

Comment: I meant `value` in general term. I completely understand `TextBox` has `Text` property, `Checkbox` has `Checked` property and so on. But how will I know the type of `var c`. Will I have to cast `c` to `control` ? If Yes, then how ?

Comment: Please ask a new question. This question is specific to finding a control with name and you said you don't want to use a loop to find it. The answer to this question is given. Just ask about a generic way to get what you called `Value`. The only solution is checking if the found control is `TextBox` then do something and if is `CheckBox` then do something else and so on.

Comment: Also when you don't know what the type of control is, it's strange that you want to find it. While your question says a different thing which you asked in comments.

Comment: I want to insert values of my controls which is inside the panel to Database. So I search all the controls according to its name (database field name is the same as control's name) and if that control found i want to retrieve it's value (value in general term not c#) according to it's type. So what is strange here huh ?

Comment: I believe data-binding is what you are looking for. Never mind. Each question is dedicated to a single topic, finding the control is closed: *But this code loop through all the controls inside that panel, that's not my exact requirement. I want to find that control without any loop.*. Please ask a new question about your new requirement. I also will share answer if I has anything to share.  Good luck :)