# Save string values via textboxes form a specific tabpage to a List<string> MyData

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am developing an application using Windows Form and C#. How can I add the `Text` of all textboxes on the current tabpage to a `List<string> Mydata`.
Here is my code below:

```
foreach(Control c in Controls){
    if((c is TextBox) && (c.Text !="")){
         if(c.Tag.ToString() == "500"){
             StaticClass.Mydata.Items.Add(c.Text);
         }
    }
}
```

NB: Mydata (List) is public on a static class.
I have a form with a tabcontrol which contains about 6 tabpages. The other tabpages have textboxes, too, but I want to retrieve only those in my example on tabindex 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Get the tabpage and call .Controls on it. Instead of this.Controls.

Comment: You can give a name to the textbox and then you can find it very easily https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls. Because the chances are the textbox may not be the control of tabpage i.e. may control of any other control which is inside the tabpage.

Comment: Texboxes has they names and the thing which is common to them is tag number.

Comment: All textboxes has it own names

Comment: Ikdhruw: The above question it not the same with the one on the link. I think I can try dereck answer and see if I can solve my logic

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to get the text from all TextBoxes within a TabPage, but only if the Tag property is equal to the string "500".

Your code is basically right, but I've modified it slightly (removed some redundant parenthesis etc.).
I'm assuming that your TabPage is named tabPage1, indexOfTabPage is the index of the TabPage and the results are placed in a local List.

You can just add the strings to a static list instead if you like.

```
int indexOfTabPage = 5;
List<string> myData = new List<string>();

foreach(Control c in this.tabControl1.TabPages[indexOfTabPage].Controls)
{
   if(c is TextBox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text) && c.Tag != null && c.Tag.ToString() == "500")
   {
      myData.Add(c.Text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you did answered my question. Let me try to implement it

Comment: I have a static class ; where I define lstData as List object. Inside the form's construction just under InitializeComponent(); ClMyData.lstData = new List<string>(); under the button on tabpage1 then I include the same code but It doesn't display those value on tabpage2 listbox

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya ok, you should make it List<string> unless you want to store something other than type string in it. Otherwise, simply use StaticClass.Mydata.Add(c.Text) rather than myData.Add(c.Text). 
In your original example you had
   StaticClass.Mydata.Items.Add(c.Text);
but List<T> doesn't have an Items property.

Comment: Am using List<string> to store values. It was a mistake

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya If that's a question, you mentioned in your original question that you wanted "retrieve only those on example on tabindex 5", so that's pointing to tab index 5.

Comment: In a class: namespace ExampleOnList
{
    public static class ClMyData
    {
        public static List<string> lstData;
    }
}

Comment: public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ClMyData.lstData = new List<string>();
        }

Comment: Under Button submit on tabpage1:         private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int indexOfTabpage = this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count-1;
            foreach (Control c in 
         this.tabControl1.TabPages[indexOfTabpage].Controls)
            {
                if ( (c is TextBox) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text) ) && (c.Tag.ToString()=="500")) {
                   if(c.Text != "") {
                        ClMyData.lstData.Add(c.Text);
                   }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya Yes, that should work. Are you seeing some unexpected results?

Comment: I try to work it on the same example for textboxes on the form it didn't work. Foreach(Control c in this.Controls){ if(c is TextBox) { clData.lstData.Add(c.Test);}} do u have an idea why isn't working Thanks

Comment: @JoelMayerMukanya Yes, it's because the textboxes are not children of the Form, but of the TabControl. 
See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void GetTextBoxValueFromCurrentTabPage()
        {
            List<string> lstTextBoxData = new List<string>();
            foreach (var textBox in tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                lstTextBoxData.Add(textBox.Text.Trim());
            }
        }

        private void GetTextBoxValueFromAllTabPages()
        {
            List<string> lstTextBoxData = new List<string>();
            foreach (TabPage tabPage in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                foreach (var textBox in tabPage.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    lstTextBoxData.Add(textBox.Text.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Hello , how can i access a textbox which is a child of groupbox and groupbox a child of tabpage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button