# set a back color to a shape from database

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this is my database and what i want to do is when i fetch the column name it should concatenate with `rectangleShape`is this possible or is there another way to do it

**my database**

```
name   check
 1       True
 2       False
```

**code**

```
while (dataReader.Read())
                {                   
                    string name= dataReader["name"].ToString();
                    string check = dataReader["check "].ToString();   
                    if (check =="True")
                    {
                        string add= "rectangleShape" + name ;
                        add.BackColor = Color.Red;  //but this doesn't work

                }
```

Comment: Since when String class has property BackColor? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is it WinForms?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yes it is WinForms

Comment: So, you have some controls that starts with "rectangleShape" and you want to find a specific one and set its background ?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten yes that is what i wanna do

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls

Comment: `TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;`
what do i write in my case `rectangleShape`