# Search Buttons By Name In Form and disable them c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a *List* in which I have stored name of few buttons. I have used this to create *List*.`

```
        List<String> seat = new List<String>(); //List name "seat". 
        for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
            seat.Add(dt.Rows[a]["SeatNo"].ToString()); //Adding values to seat from a column of table.("SeatNo" column has button names).
```

What I want is that all the buttons in form whose *Name* is same as those Names containing in the *List*, to get disabled.

I thought of traversing the *List* and disabling the buttons whose name matches with name in the List but I cannot get the logic for that.

I am a beginner in C#, Please explain it in simple terms. Thank you in advance.

Comment: in what way are the buttons stored?

Comment: Its been 3 days since I showed to you how to write it

Comment: All the buttons are in Panel1. And I have stored the names of those I want in Table.

Comment: Sorry bro I am a beginner in C#. I did not understand complex methods which you used. I know that is my fault. Could you please explain it simply

Comment: I think this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) article helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put in comments that repeat what the code is doing. Name collections with plural names. Create your List like so:

```
var seats = new List<String>();
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
    seats.Add(row["SeatNo"].ToString()); // "SeatNo" column has button names
```

You could also use LINQ to create the `List`:

```
var seats = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["SeatNo"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Then you just go through the seats and disable the matching controls:

```
foreach (var seat in seats) {
    var controls = this.Controls.Find(seat, true);
    foreach (var control in controls)
        control.Enabled = false;
}
```

If you are worried the names might conflict with other names, you can verify they are buttons:

```
foreach (var seat in seats) {
    var controls = this.Controls.Find(seat, true);
    foreach (var control in controls)
        if (control is Button)
            control.Enabled = false;
}
```