# Toggle buttons on and off based on database value in C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to make a button inside a webform visible if data available. 
I have a database with a column name NCID, then in a views I count the NCID's.
and I a have btn1 till btn9 hidden.
If NCID Count is 1 show button btn1,
if NCID Count is 2 then show btn1 and btn2.

How can I target the Button ID to make it visible or hide it?

I tried the following but it is not working for me.

```
while (sr.Read())
{
    string NCID = sr["NCID"].ToString();
    int nc2 = Convert.ToInt32(NCID);
    int x = 1;

    do
    {
        string btnx = "btn" + x;
        btnx.Visible = true;

        x++;
    } while (x <= nc2);
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: Is this webforms, mvc, wpf?

Comment: `I tried the following but it is not working for me!!` Define `not working`. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: sorry, it is a webform

Comment: See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: By not working I mean the button remain hidden.

Comment: when I use this the myControl1 is always null

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows Forms app, you can use:

```
Controls.Find(btnx, true).First().Visible = true;
```

[Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

If it's WebForms, you can use:

```
FindControl(btnx).Visible = true;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried Controls.FindControl(btnx).Visible = true; then I get an error "ControlCollection does not contain a definition for FindControl"

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you're declaring controls in HTML?

Comment: string NCID = sr["NCID"].ToString();
                            int nc2 = Convert.ToInt32(NCID);
                            int x = 1;
                            do
                            {
                                 string btnx = "btn" + x;
                                Controls.FindControl(btnx).Visible = true;
                                x++;
                            } while (x <= nc2);

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I did WebForms.  I updated the answer to show you can just use FindControl, not Controls.FindControl, after confirming this works in an old WebForms project.

Answer (score 0):

(see jareds answer)

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) //smaller then ammount of lines returned      
{
  Controls.Find(btnx + i).Visible = true; //add visibility to wichever control (found by name) you wanted to add
}
```