# It's possible convert string into Label name?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C# and Windows Forms, i would like to use the name of a `Label` as a parameter of another function, like this:

```
 startBox(label_box, "11", Color.Red);
```

Definition of `startBox`:

```
  private void startBox(Label label, string text, Color color) {
        label.BackColor = color;
        label.Visible = true;
        label.Enabled = true;
        label.Text = text;
    }
```

But, **is there any way to convert an `string` to the name of a `Label`?**
In my case, `label_box` is a `string`.

**ps¹.** I need to do this because i have `N` `Labels` and the name is should be typed by the user.

**ps².** To Invoke a method using a `string` i used the `MethodInfo`.

**EDIT:** The solution using [Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls) does not apply. In my case, a string is given as an input, if the string is the name of one of the labels the function is called.

*Thank you, and sorry for the spelling flaws in English.*

Comment: winforms? wpf? what tech are you using?

Comment: windows forms,  question edited :)

Comment: I think you want this: [How to: Access Controls by using the Controls Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i know the name of the `Labels` (Controls it's just to get all the controls). What I need is to get a string as an input and check for a label with that name, and call the function, thks :)

Comment: See the first answer in the dupe. Looks to me like exactly what you need: `Label label = this.Controls.Find(label_box, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;` Or more simply: `Label label = this.Controls[label_box] as Label` (but you need to ensure is exists and is not nested).

Answer (score 1):

so you want to be able to operate on a label, where the name of the label is supplied as input. I would do this with a dictions

```
var lDict = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
lDict["l1"] = Label1;
lDict["l2"] = Label2;
....
```

then

```
void Func(string labelName)
{
  var label = lDict[labelName];
  label.Visible = true;
  ...
}
```

you could do all sorts of complicated reflection tings but that feels like overkill