# How can I set the value of Input element without id attribute on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

There is an input element in a form whose runat attribute is server. I don't want to define id attibute to it.
Following code gives error, because an string has not Value property.
How can I do this?

```
<form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
    <div id="inpdiv">
          <input type='text' name='inp1' />
    </div>
</form>
```

In code behind wrong one:

Request.Form["inp1"].Value = "S";

Comment: Check [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898610/5519709)

Comment: @SelimYıldız - that's what i was thinking, but can you actually find a control that does not have `runat="server"`? only the form has it.

Comment: If you want to find the control from code behind you have to use runat="server" attribute on control. And then you can use Control.FindControl.