# Controls.Find() returning null

Tags: c#, winforms

The following piece of code gets all labels named "label_bluep"+i where i is between 1 and 5.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Label labelname = (Label)this.Controls.Find("label_bluep" + (i), false).FirstOrDefault();
        labelname.Parent = pictureBox_background;
    }
```

When the code runs, this works fine.
If I called the Controls.Find() method again for the same object e.g copying and pasting that same code to get this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Label labelname = (Label)this.Controls.Find("label_bluep" + (i), false).FirstOrDefault();
        labelname.Parent = pictureBox_background;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Label labelname = (Label)this.Controls.Find("label_bluep" + (i), false).FirstOrDefault();
        labelname.Visible = true;
    }
```

I get the exception `labelname was null.`What's the reason for this?

Comment: Is it because the label's parent is now the picture box and not `this` anymore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: @Crowcoder that does indeed seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of [`ControlCollection.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) tells if the controls of children of the current control should also be searched.

In the first loop you made all labels to children of `pictureBox_background`. So you need to use `true` to find the labels again:

```
Controls.Find("label_bluep" + i, true);
```

or to search only children of `pictureBox_background`:

```
pictureBox_background.Controls.Find("label_bluep" + i, false);
```