# Assign Array Position to a Label Tag Property

Tags: arrays, vb.net, tags, label

I want to assign an array to the Tag property of 16 Labels. This is what I came up with:

```
Label1.Tag = FotoArray(0)
Label2.Tag = FotoArray(1)
Label3.Tag = FotoArray(2)
Label4.Tag = FotoArray(3)
Label5.Tag = FotoArray(4)
Label6.Tag = FotoArray(5)
Label7.Tag = FotoArray(6)
Label8.Tag = FotoArray(7)
Label9.Tag = FotoArray(8)
Label10.Tag = FotoArray(9)
Label11.Tag = FotoArray(10)
Label12.Tag = FotoArray(11)
Label16.Tag = FotoArray(12)
Label13.Tag = FotoArray(13)
Label15.Tag = FotoArray(14)
Label14.Tag = FotoArray(15)
```

Is there a way to do it in a shorter way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find control by name from Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Label16.Tag = FotoArray(12)` is a typo, this should do the work:

```
For counter As Integer = 1 To 16
    Dim label As Label = Me.Controls.Find("Label" & counter, True).FirstOrDefault()
    If Not label Is Nothing Then
        label.Tag = FotoArray(counter - 1)
    End If
Next
```

You can also simply use `Me.Controls(name)` instead. The updated code would look like this:

```
For counter As Integer = 1 To 16
    Dim label As Label = Me.Controls("Label" & counter)
    If Not label Is Nothing Then
        label.Tag = FotoArray(counter - 1)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Neither method will compile with Option Strict On which it should be.