# How to load multiple images into picture boxes using a loop without repeating code?

Tags: c#, loops, refactoring, picturebox, loadimage

I want to use the incrementing of the for loop to access different picture boxes and images in the resource folder. I could type it all out as I have shown below but I would like to "program" it more. (Hope my question makes sense)

```
private void btnUse19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string applicationDirectory = Application.ExecutablePath;

    //Using my student number as an index to get the file path of the application.
    string editedApplicationDirectory = applicationDirectory.Substring(0, applicationDirectory.IndexOf("19001700"));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        string spineNumber = i.ToString();

        string pbSpineNum = "pbSpine" + spineNumber;
        string picNameNum = "Spine " + spineNumber + ".png";

        //this is what im trying to do but does not work
        pbSpineNum.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\"+picNameNum);
    }

    //Dont want to have to do this
    pbSpine1.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 1.png");
    pbSpine2.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 2.png");
    pbSpine3.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 3.png");
    pbSpine4.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 4.png");
    pbSpine5.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 5.png");
    pbSpine6.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 6.png");
    pbSpine7.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 7.png");
    pbSpine8.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 8.png");
    pbSpine9.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 9.png");
    pbSpine10.Image = Image.FromFile(editedApplicationDirectory + "19001700" + "\\Resources\\Spine 10.png");
}
```

Comment: maybe you're after this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898610/2408978)

Comment: @OlivierRogier i just tried using the array i am still getting the same error of: String does not contain a definition for image and no acceptable extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of picture boxes and the counter to refactor and reduce all to one line moved in the loop:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

string pathExe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string pathImagesPattern = Path.Combine(pathExe, "Resources", "Spine {0}.png");

for ( int index = 1; index <= 10; index++ )
{
  var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
  string pathImage = string.Format(pathImagesPattern, index);
  pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(pathImage);
  pictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox);
}
```

I changed names to be more talking and clean, as well as the path according to what I seem to have understood that you were doing.

Now you can use the list to process items like adding them in a panel, or the form:

```
MyPanel.Controls.AddRange(pictureBoxes.ToArray());
```

And you can access them like that:

```
pictureBoxes[0].Location = ...
```

But you should initialize each control in the loop using certain calculated variables for rendering:

```
pictureBox.Location = new Point(posX, posY);
```

You might need to promote this list as a class data member if you plan to use it outside of the method:

```
private List<PictureBox> PictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
```

Another improvement for a cleaner code will be to use a constant or a variable instead of the literal in the loop itself:

```
private int PictureBoxesCount = 10;

PictureBoxes.Clear();
for ( int index = 1; index <= PictureBoxesCount; index++ )
```

If this number is fixed, you can use a const and also a fixed array instead of a `List`:

```
const private int PictureBoxCount = 10;

private PictureBox[] PictureBoxes = new PictureBox[PictureBoxCount];

for ( int index = 0; index < PictureBoxes.Length; index++ )
{
  string pathImage = string.Format(pathImagesPattern, index);
  PictureBoxes[index] = new PictureBox();
  PictureBoxes[index].Image = Image.FromFile(pathImage);
}
```

---

If the picture boxes are created using the Visual Studio Form Designer and are already created, you can simply use this preallocated array:

```
  PictureBoxes = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                         .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("pbSpine"))
                         .OrderBy(p => p.Name.Length)
                         .ThenBy(p => p.Name)
                         .ToArray();

  for ( int index = 0; index < PictureBoxes.Length; index++ )
  {
    string pathImage = string.Format(pathImagesPattern, index);
    PictureBoxes[index].Image = Image.FromFile(pathImage);
  }
```

But unlike the fully dynamic version, here we may encounter matching problems between the indexes of controls and images.

I therefore do not recommend to use this with controls already placed on the form unless we know what we are doing and that we control the process in a robust way.

Comment: I think you're right but im having trouble working it into my program, so I'm going to do it the easier way. But it was a good learning oppertunity.

Comment: I really wish i understood more, but i can't seem to grasp this 100%.‍♂️

Comment: What don't you understand?